# Implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ (string.h included)

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

I am trying to solve this warning for some while but I really don't know how is something like that possible.

gcc command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0   -c -o myString.o myString.c
```

> myString.c: In function ‘string_toCharArr’: myString.c:47:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   return strdup(s->data);

File myString.h

```
#ifndef INCL_MYSTRING_H
#define INCL_MYSTRING_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct sString{
    unsigned len;
    unsigned actLen;
    char *data;
} string;


string *new_string();

bool string_append(string *s, char c);

char *string_toCharArr(string *s);

void string_clear(string *s);

void string_destroy(string *s);

#endif /* INCL_MYSTRING_H */
```

File myString.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "myString.h"

string *new_string(){
    //
}

bool string_append(string *s, char c){
    //
}

char *string_toCharArr(string *s){
    return strdup(s->data);
}

unsigned string_getLength(string *s){ 
    //
}

void string_clear(string *s){
    //
}

void string_destroy(string *s){
    //
}
```

The same happens with **fileno()** and **readlink()** with **unistd.h** included.

*gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4*

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have saved your file after adding the include line?

Comment: Please search for errors like this before posting. The linked duplicate was literally the first hit on Google.

Comment: `strdup` is no standard C function.